# how to remove non-schema params from the query

Tags: jsonschema, fastify, ajv

according to the [fastify 4.0 docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/), the default options for Ajv include `removeAdditional: true`. I have a `queryString` schema, and when I send a query with a param that is not in the schema, I expect that param to be removed. But no such thing happens. The schema itself is pretty run-of-the-mill

```
querystring: {
    type: "object",
    properties: { … }
}
```

Some of my params are of type array, and there too I would like any additional values (outside of those specified via `enum` to be removed. How can I achieve this?

**update:** I am adding the actual schema below (with some info snipped for brevity)

```js
{
  '$schema': 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema',
  '$id': 'https://example.com/treatments.schema.json',
  title: 'Treatments',
  summary: 'Fetches treatments',
  description: 'Treatments are…',
  response: {},
  querystring: {
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
      treatmentId: {
          type: "string",
          maxLength: 32,
          minLength: 32,
          description: "A 32 character string: treatmentId=388D179E0D564775C3925A5B93C1C407"
      },
      … <snipped> …
    }
  },
  tags: [ 'zenodeo' ]
}
```

I know the schema is being validated because `http://localhost:3010/v3/treatments?treatmentId=foo` gives an error `{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"querystring/treatmentId must NOT have fewer than 32 characters"}` (that is good ) but the `additionalProperties: false` constraint is still not working because `http://localhost:3010/v3/treatments?foo=bar` gives no error and `foo` is also not removed from `request.query` (that is not good )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `removeAdditional: true` you must still set `additionalProperties: false` on your schema:

```
querystring: {
  type: "object",
  properties: { … },
  additionalProperties: false
}
```

See https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#additionalproperties

You can also change the default behavior to `removeAdditional: 'all'` in which case you don't have to set `additionalProperties: false` on your schema.

See about halfway down the page here: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/

Comment: sorry for the super-late response (I was traveling)… thanks for your response. I tried what you suggested by it doesn't work. I have updated the original question with more info (as it is not possible to put it in comment here) to illustrate what is going on vs what I would like

Comment: ok, discovered the error… it was a mistake on my part. @Glenn's answer helped. Thanks